# Can $\int_0^\infty f (x) \, dx$ exist if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, improper-integrals, harmonic-numbers

Is is possible to have a function for which $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist, but $\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx$ exists and is finite?

I think I've found an example actually, but I'm not sure it works. Let $H_n$ be the $n$th harmonic number. Consider $f$ such that $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(x) = (-1)^{n}$ for $x \in [H_n , H_{n + 1})$. It seems that
$$
\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n + 1}}{n} = \log 2
$$
even though $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ doesn't exist. Does this work?

Comment: I believe that does work! Another example is $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is an integer and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. (One can make a continuous version of this if desired.)

Comment: Ah that example's even better. Makes it very clear that the result should be true and for nonnegative functions no less. The only remaining question for me is if it can be true for nonnegative functions for which $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx > 0$.

Comment: Sure, just replace the single nonzero values in my first example with thinner and thinner (but still positive-measure) peaks. (Such functions are really good to have in your toolbox of potential examples or counterexamples!)

Comment: @GregMartin that's a better example than I even asked for. As I phrased it, you could just take your example and set $f(x) = 1$ on $[0,1]$. This is beyond the scope of this question, but I now wonder about strictly positive functions.

Comment: Examples with strictly positive functions exist and are based on the same principle but they are more difficult to write. You may use hats functions defined  as in the answer on each $[n-0.5,n+0.5)$ but with non-linear edges. (For example with $x^n$ for the $n$-th peak.)

Comment: @nicomezi thanks. I'll remove the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You example is correct. Note that you based your idea on an oscillating function, however, we can also give an example with a non-negative one.

Consider hats functions with maximum value $1$ centered on integers such that the hat width at for the $n$-th is $\frac 1 {n^2}$. Thus, the area of the $n$-th hat function is $\frac 1{2n^2}$. Now, define $f$ as the sum of those hats functions, thus : $$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx =\sum_{n>0} \frac 1{2n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

And of course the limit of $f$ does not exist since $f(n) = 1$ and $f(n + 0.5) =0$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: And if one wants a strictly positive function, as the OP commented, then just add $e^{-x}$ to $f(x)$ or something. (Moral: very often, continuity or strict positivity or similar properties aren't really barriers—examples without these properties can very often be easily converted to examples with these properties.)

Answer (score 1):

Another famous examples are the Fresnel integrals:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{+\infty}\cos(x^2)\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$$
And it's also important to note that if the limit exists and it's not zero, then the integral must diverge.